# plt.gray() is not working and displaying original color image in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow, imread

With the following code, *plt.gray()* is not working and showing a colour image instead of grayscale. Even I put *cmap="gray"* separately in *plt.imshow*, still it is showing the image in colour. Thank you. (Please note, the original image *smallimage.jpg* is a colour image)

```
from matplotlib import image as image, pyplot as plt
img  = image.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/Z ML Lab/data/smallimage.jpg')
plt.gray()
plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is RGB color.  From the `imshow` docstring:

```
cmap : str or `~matplotlib.colors.Colormap`, default: :rc:`image.cmap`
    The Colormap instance or registered colormap name used to map
    scalar data to colors. This parameter is ignored for RGB(A) data.
```

Note in particular *"This parameter is ignored for RGB(A) data."*

If you want to display the image as grayscale, you'll have to "flatten" the colors somehow.  There are several ways to do this; one is to display just one of the color channels, e.g.

```
plt.imshow(img[:, :, 0], cmap="gray")  # Display the red channel
```

Another popular method is to take a weighted average of the channels, with weights [0.299, 0.587, 0.113]:

```
imshow(img @ [0.299, 0.587, 0.113], cmap='gray')
```

See ["Converting colour to grayscale"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_colour_to_grayscale) for more ideas.